# ajax form freezes in grails file submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, ajaxform

I'm trying submit files asynchronously in grails app using AjaxForm. For small files it works pretty good, but when i try with a large file, ajaxForm never triggers the function error or success. In both cases (large and small files), all the files are stored successfully in the server side. This is my code:

```
var opts = {

            beforeSubmit:   AntesEnvio,
            error:          ErrorEnvio,
            uploadProgress: ProgresoEnvio,
            success:        CorrectoEnvio

        }

$('div#modal-cargar-ficheros .upload-form').ajaxForm(opts)

function CorrectoEnvio(){

            do somethings ...

        }
function ErrorEnvio(){

            do somethings ...

        }
```

Any one help me!!
Thanks in advance.

============= EDIT ==========================

I tried to test the application without using AJAX, and it's the same, the server processes all the data but does not answer. I check the database and files on the server side and everything is fine, but when it finishes uploading files the browser is saying: Waiting for localhost ... and never finishes

My gsp Form:

```
<g:uploadForm class="upload-form" method="POST"
                          controller="fileManager" action="upload">

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="area-msgs">

                    </div>

                    %{-- Selector de Ficheros/Carpeta oculto --}%
                    <input name="files[]" class="upload" type="file"  id="upload-files" webkitdirectory />

                    <div class="area-seleccion">
                        <div class="boton-select pull-left">
                            <div id="select-files" class="btn btn-large" >
                                <span class="icon-folder"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="texto-cant pull-left">0 ficheros seleccionados</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <g:submitButton name="btn-submit-files"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        value="Enviar">
                    </g:submitButton>
                </div>

            </g:uploadForm>
```

My upload action in controller:

```
def upload() {

        //Recibo los datos de la vista

        //Si no existe un directorio para el usuario
        //en el servidor lo creo

        def fullPath = 'uploads'            +
                        File.separator      +
                        session.user.userid +
                        File.separator


        def userFolder = new File(fullPath)
        if (!userFolder.exists()){

            userFolder.mkdirs()

        }

        //Si vienen el (los) fichero (os) hago el envío
        //al servidor

        def resp = [status: 'OK']

        request.getFiles("files[]").each { file ->

            def documentItem = new Document()
            documentItem.docName = file.originalFilename

            // Genero un numero aleatorio para evitar
            // nombres duplicados
            def num = (new Random()).nextInt(99999)
            def fileName = num + '_' + file.originalFilename

            //Si existe un fichero con ese nombre
            //vuelvo a intentarlo

            while (new File(fullPath + fileName).exists()){

                num = (new Random()).nextInt(99999)
                fileName = num + '_' + file.originalFilename

            }

            documentItem.fullPath = fullPath + fileName
            documentItem.size = FileUtilService.humanSize(file.getSize())

            //Una vez creado el nombre unico guardo
            //el fichero en el servidor
            file.transferTo( new File(documentItem.fullPath) )

            if (!documentItem.save()){

                resp = [status: 'Error']

            }

        } // --> Fin de recorrer cada fichero subido

        render resp as JSON

    }
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: information you have provided is not sufficient. Could you please ensure if using chrome by going to console if there is no js error.

Comment: thanks for answering, I already updated my question.